# adding 10 integers into $t0 and printing the result, not sure if implementation correct and why it is not printing? Mars MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

```
    .data
    a1: .word 2
    a2: .word 3
    a3: .word 5
    a4: .word 7
    a5: .word 11 
    a6: .word 13 
    a7: .word 17
    a8: .word 19
    a9: .word 23 
    a10: .word 29 

main:

    lw $t1,a1
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a2 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a3 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a4 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a5 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a6
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a7 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a8 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a9 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 
    lw $t1,a10 
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 

    li $v0, 1
    lw $a0, $t0
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I want to understand if I am adding the integers stored in labels correctly in $t0. and if it is correctly implemented why am I not able to print the value stored in $t0?

Comment: Don't put your code in `.data`.  Switch back to `.text` before main.  I assume that's wrong; you didn't describe what actually happens or any error messages.

Comment: There were no error messages. Thank you I think that was the problem. I got the error : Error in C:\Users\wasei\Downloads\addIntegers line 44 column 1: "lw": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: lw $t1,-100($t2). So I changed this line to lw $a0, 8($t0). Still not printing value

Comment: MARS normally accepts `lw $reg,  symbol` (like you're using)  as a pseudo-instruction for `lui`/`lw` to construct and use a 32-bit absolute address.  Of course it'd be more efficient to just `la` once and `lw` with offsets of 0, 4, 8, 12, etc. relative to `a0`.

Comment: li $v0,1
move $a0,$t0
syscall. I tried changing the code to that. I am just having trouble printing the value stored in $t0. nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you mean by _"not able to print the value stored in $t0"_. The value is printed just fine in MARS, assuming that you've changed the `lw $a0,$t0` to `move $a0,$t0` and added `.text` before the line with `main:`.

Comment: nevermind i only assembled the program i didn't realize i have to run the program as well after. i am very new this is embarassing thank you all